# Smart Object itself is not resized when resizing an entire image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, resize, smartobject

I have an image of size `100px x 100px` and a bunch of smart objects of size `10px x 10px` in it.

When I resize the image using `Image > Image Size` by 200% - all my vector objects and smart objects are resized just fine. But when I open the smart object for editing, I can see its size is still `10px x 10px`. (should be `20px x 20px`).

When I resize the smart object while editing it and hit save, it is `40px x 40px` in size. So looks like Photoshop is still making it double sized (as I resized an entire image to have 200% in width / height).

Am I doing something wrong? **Is there a better way how to resize an image with smart objects included?**

Comment: Smart object is a container. -- It's kinda like if you think of something like a video projector: The **projected image** is `smart object` and the **original image** is the `smart object content`. You can edit the **projected image**, but the **original image** stays just the way it was. If you however edit the **original image**, the **projected image** changes as well. -- I hope this makes sense :)

Comment: Yes, make sense now. Thanks a lot for a quick resp!

Comment: @Joonas -- should make that an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Smart object is a container.

It's kinda like if you think of something like a video projector: The **projected image** is `smart object` and the **original image** is the `smart object content`. You can edit the **projected image**, but the **original image** stays just the way it was. If you however edit the **original image**, the **projected image** changes as well.